# Can Polynomials be positive definite?

Tags: matrices, fourier-analysis

It seems to me that polynomial functions are ,trivially, not positive-definite ([for definition](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function) )because of growth property of p.d functions. Am I right?

Comment: What about $x \mapsto x^2+1$?

Comment: are you using the [dynamical systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function#In_dynamical_systems) definition or the [analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function#In_analysis) definition?

Comment: @flawr $x^2+1$ is not p.d.you can choose $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and let$z=i, w=-i.$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom In analysis

Comment: What are $a,b,z,w$ in your counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any positive definite function must [satisfy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570088/prove-that-if-f-is-continuous-at-0-it-is-continuous-on-mathbbr)
$$
|f(t)| \leq |f(0)| \quad t \in \Bbb R
$$
As you say, this is trivially never true for any non-constant polynomial function, since for any polynomial $f$, $\lim_{t \to \infty}|f(t)| = \infty$.